# Is there a way to modify the width of elements in the IntelliJ statusbar (esp, the current git branch)

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I know that I can hover over the element and get a tool-tip, or click on the item to see the current checkout, but I frequently am doing a commit and I have to close the commit window to see the branch name (in order to verify what branch I'm on.)

My company dictates branch names; I cannot make them small enough to fit.

[image]

In the case above, the full branch name is "feature/TS-1234-outbound", and it's particularly the "TS-1234" part I need to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is not. However there is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73669) for this problem, which has Major priority. So feel free to vote for it or leave a comment so that it hopefully gets fixed faster.

As a workaround you can bind some keyboard shortcut to Branches pop-up menu to be able to see current branch name without hovering over the Git status bar widget:

[image]